# Doing "group by" in django but still retaining complete object

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I want to do a GROUP BY in Django. I saw answers on Stack Overflow that recommend:

```
Member.objects.values('designation').annotate(dcount=Count('designation'))
```

This works, but the problem is you're getting a `ValuesQuerySet` instead of a `QuerySet`, so the queryset isn't giving me full objects but only specific fields. I want to get complete objects.

Of course, since we're grouping we need to choose which object to take out of each group; I want a way to specify the object (e.g. take the one with the biggest value in a certain field, etc.)

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: I blogged about a similar question a few years ago: http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/08/14/getting-related-item-aggregate/ - does that help you?

Comment: How about just use a raw query? I found that when doing more complex things, its better to skip the ORM.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - You should answer the question with your suggestion rather than merely post a comment. You might want to put an extract from your blog post in the answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Could this work? `Document.objects.filter(id__in=Document.objects.order_by('title').distinct('title')).order_by('anything_you_want')` ? Try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to make two queries, you could do the following:

```
dcounts = Member.objects.values('id', 'designation').annotate(dcount=Count('designation')).order_by('-dcount')
member = Member.objects.get(id=dcounts.first()['id'])
```

If you wanted the top five objects by `dcount`, you could do the following:

```
ids = [dcount['id'] for dcount in dcounts[:5]]
members = Member.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't necessarily need to GROUP BY, but just want to limit your selection to one item per field (eg, the MAX value of a certain field).

Can you try getting distinct objects by field, such as

In Postgres

`Member.objects.order_by('designation').distinct('designation')`

In any other database

`Member.objects.distinct('designation')`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct